# How to re-export an enum under a different name in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums

I'd like to provide a simpler interface in my library (in a React application) for exported members of another library (monaco-editor in this case). For this I created an index.ts file which does re-export a number of types, where I removed an inner namespace. This works nicely:

```js
import { languages } from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api";

export type FoldingRange = languages.FoldingRange;
export type FoldingContext = languages.FoldingContext;
export type FoldingRangeKind = languages.FoldingRangeKind;
```

except for the last line, because `FoldingRangeKind` is an enum. I cannot use `export enum` here as that expects a full enum definition.

Another option would be:

`export import FoldingRangeKind = languages.FoldingRangeKind;`

but unfortunately, this is not accepted by Babel. It results in this error:

> import =`is not supported by @babel/plugin-transform-typescript
>   Please consider using`import  from '';` alongside Typescript's --allowSyntheticDefaultImports option.

A default import wouldn't help here, so I wonder what to do instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enum is not a type, but an object. Its values are values too, thus you need to assign them to constant instead.

```ts
enum languages {
    FoldingRange,
    FoldingContext,
    FoldingRangeKind
}

export const FoldingRange = languages.FoldingRange;
export const FoldingContext = languages.FoldingContext;
export const FoldingRangeKind = languages.FoldingRangeKind;

interface iLanguages {
    FoldingRange: 0,
    FoldingContext: 1,
}

export type FoldingRange = iLanguages["FoldingRange"];
export type FoldingContext = iLanguages["FoldingContext"];
export type FoldingRangeKind = languages.FoldingRangeKind;
```

This is what is then compiled ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBANghiA5mOjgGcoG8BQV9QBiA9jACYCWSASgmgDR4EnlWIDCxIALsAB7dGBIqUo06wANJUyOAL44c-AA7EATtygBjLuk0sxiWkmBQAvLDoo06AHQG2xtAG4lfVRu279otpx78mhbwSNYY9r5I-rwCrirqmjogeiKs4ibSIGTmlqGo4Q7paJlkrjhUvGoAZnBaphQAMlb5mLjChUYSAFxQAAxCzJEcXDHcPQCMjApuHprcAJ7Kph1OphaNzTYA2gBEKxI7ALpx7glQC0uphtGBORt523tDNwJHJ7Pni8tDqyU5IcgWhE0p0MjJnEA)). Hopefully, this clears it up for you.

```js
var languages;
(function (languages) {
    languages[languages["FoldingRange"] = 0] = "FoldingRange";
    languages[languages["FoldingContext"] = 1] = "FoldingContext";
    languages[languages["FoldingRangeKind"] = 2] = "FoldingRangeKind";
})(languages || (languages = {}));

export const FoldingRange = languages.FoldingRange;
export const FoldingContext = languages.FoldingContext;
export const FoldingRangeKind = languages.FoldingRangeKind;
```

Comment: Even though `FoldingRange` and `FoldingContext` are interface it doesn't make your answser bad. The only issue I have to solve now is that I no longer can use `FoldingRangeKind` as a function result. But that's a different issue.

Comment: Sorry, I only read the enum part... I edited the answer, it should still work

Comment: The interface members could get out of sync with the enum values and, more importantly, they do not have the same _type_ as the enum members. They are number literal types and will be compatible with unrelated enums. You can resolve both issues by writing `export const FoldingRange = languages.FoldingRange; export type FoldingRange = typeof FoldingRange;` and so on